# Reserved names in "declare function"?

Tags: pgfmath, pgfmathparse

This must be my week for stepping on reserved words... please look at this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\formula}[1]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rpval}{#1}%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[assume math mode=true, fixed, precision=3]{\rpval}{\frpval}%
    \frpval
}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{declare function={%
        R0 = 2.0;
        X = 0.5*R0;
        ON = 3;
        OFF(\x) = \x + 1;
        AFF(\x) = \x + 1;
}}

%  works
X is \formula{X}

% fails
ON is \formula{ON}

% works
AFF is \formula{AFF(1)}

% fails
OFF is \formula{OFF(1)}
\end{document}
```

The second and fourth line fail with

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `O' or `ON' (in 'ON').

! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `O' or `OF' (in 'OFF(1)').
```

...and it seems it is doing the same for every constant starting with `O` 
are creating problems.

I *think* I am doing something very silly...

Comment: It doesn't have to start with `O`. All of `ONN`, `NON` and `NNO` fail...

Comment: ...lowercase `o` works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** This has been [fixed](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/167a78ebf3f4920939dbcf593098d639d829642a) and your document should work fine after the next Ti*k*Z/PGF release.

---

In `pgfmathparser.code.tex` you see:

```latex
\pgfmath@tokens@make{functional}{_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}
```

without an `O`.

`O` doesn't seem to be a reserved keyword (after all, you get an “Unknown operator” error), thus I believe this is a bug.

Providing the missing definition:

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\pgfmath@token@functional@O{O}
\makeatother
```

seems to solve the problem.

I just find it curious that you are the first person to try to use an `O` there :-)