# footnotedistance key undefined error in mdframed

Tags: errors, mdframed, key-value

My preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=black!10,
linecolor=black,
innerleftmargin=12pt,
innerrightmargin=12pt,
innertopmargin=12pt,
innerbottommargin=12pt,
splittopskip=16.5pt,
splitbottomskip=12pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
footnotedistance=22pt,
linewidth=4pt]{dBox}
\begin{document}

\begin{dBox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{dBox}

\end{document}
```

I got the error `Package kvsetkeys Error: Undefined key footnotedistance`.

If I comment the line `footnotedistance=22pt`, then it works fine, The version of `mdframed` what I use is `Package: mdframed 2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed`, please suggest what went wrong in my code...

Hope, it may require update of `mdframed`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in the documentation (or rather, in the code). The documentation says `footnotedistance`, but the code actually defines `footenotedistance`, with the extra `e`. The code should work if you change that.

This is unlikely to be fixed, as the last activity in the [`mdframed` GitHub](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed) was in 2014, but I filed an [issue](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/issues/35) anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this works.... I wondered no one realized this till date...

Comment: @MadyYuvi It happens ;-) For example, in 11 years, nobody tried to use an [`O` in a function name in Ti*k*Z](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518986/134574).

Comment: Ha ha ha... :-D, it's interesting...